# Change Text Direction (Bi-Di) Settings from Left to Right (LTR) to Right to Left (RTL) in Text Box

Tags: linux-mint, language, cinnamon

I'm using Linux Mint 18.2 (Sonya) with Cinnamon.

I'm writing text inside text boxes on various applications (Chromium, Firefox).
I was wondering, how can I change the text direction from LTR (Left to Right) to TRL (Right to Left) and vice versa?

In Windows it is done using Right Ctrl + Shift / Left Ctrl + Shift.

P. S.
I'm not talking about Open Office but text boxes in general.

Comment: https://shlomil.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/changing-text-direction-and-gnome.html

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RTLTeam

Comment: To BiDi Support (Which doesn't work well in some cases) in Firefox - http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=618249.

Answer (score 4):

It's `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `X` for me on Firefox + LXDE. Works in both directions, LTR to RTL and RTL to LTR.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`U` to [enter a character by code point](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#ctrlshiftu).

What you're looking for are the [LRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)(`200E`)/[RLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)(`200F`) characters.

So `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`U` and then `2`, `0`, `0`, `F`, for example.

I don't know of an easier way. Perhaps some kind of binding.

Comment: Is there a way to make a wish list for a keyboard shortcut for that in Linux? Like in Windows? Thank You.

Comment: You mean a feature request, perhaps?

Comment: Yea, "Linux Wish List" where I can add my feature request.

Comment: The problem is not with Linux but with some the GUI toolkits used in Linux. A good start would probably be the Gnome bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/
The relevant component is probably GTK+/GtkTextView.
Before you post a feature request I would suggest reading all the old bugs regarding BiDi support and report only if you can add new information (or just add your comment to old bugs).